# Display dropdown menu from firestore using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way I can populate a dropdown list with values stored in Firestore and have it's corresponding data exported to fields? For example, I want document names as main dropdown menu and its corresponding fields as sub-dropdown list, if I select from main dropdown list. It should show only fields of that document in the sub dropdown list. I am asking as a complete beginner to NOSQL and coding in general, so any help is appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the code that you've tried so far? At least the Firestore structure and the dropdown?